# How can I detect, on iOS, if the number that I've dialed is busy?

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I detect, on iOS, if the number that I've dialed is busy?

Comment: You can't. You can't force the phone to dial, either.

Comment: Hi quixoto I have seen an app in appStore.Here is a http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/auto-redial-helper/id386968727?mt=8.I want to do the same.

Comment: The reviews make it seem like it can't place a call either.

Comment: The app mentioned does not actually re-dial it just alerts with a notification to re-dial

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless your application placed the calls using VoIP/SIP and you implemented that within the application yourself.

Comment: I wish I did but nobodies paid me yet to write one!  It's something I looked into from an abstract perspective.  A kind of "I'll probably have to write something that does this in the future, how would I do it.".  I do know that it is possible as there are voip based apps that ddi in the store and I've spoken to the guys that wrote it.